# is there a .NET or REST (http) API for EMC (VNX\VMAX) arrays

Tags: rest, powershell, emc

my requirement is quite simple, just want to connect to emc storage server and get the storage information.
   i googled the web and found someone mentioned emc have the apis, but i did not get the details, so i want to know is there a rest api for connecting.
my second option is using ESIPSToolKit,but it need power shell and a windows server machine, a little annoying.

Thank you in advance.

here are some details, hope can help some one:
1) vnx and vmax are two very different product line.
2) ViPR have the rest api to manage vnx and vmax.
3) unisphere only support vmax for rest api
4) Celerra xml api only support file in vnx, no block support

Comment: here are some details, hope can help some one:

Answer (score 1):

Unisphere for VMAX has a REST API. It is present in current Unisphere 8.03 and back to 1.4 or so. Note there is a big gap as we jumped from 1.51 to 8.0. Sean Cummings has a great blog where he explores U4VMAX rest API. If you want to proviso and manage ViPR is best but U4VMAX is capable.

http://scummins.com/unisphere-for-vmax-rest-api/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It actually does because Unisphere for VMAX is the software that manages a VMAX. It is an option but one that is universally purchased with a VMAX. So if you want to access a REST API to get stats from a VMAX, you do so through Unisphere for VMAX.

Answer (score 0):

Going to investigate more for you, but at this point the easy answer is no. There is no REST interface for them natively. However, you can front end all your storage arrays with ViPR. ViPR will give you the ability to access the arrays through REST. This will require SMI-S as well

There is also an early attempt at open sourcing a python REST interface for VMAX3
https://github.com/scottbri/unisphere-rest-client

Comment: you are right, only the ViPR has REST api to vnx and vmax

Comment: if you're interested, ViPR is now completely open source (renamed CoprHD), available on GitHub: https://github.com/CoprHD